# Label to control checkbox

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I've been playing around with the CSS hack to use `<label for=""..` to control the toggle for a checkbox. Here's a [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JoVvML).

When I add another `<input>`, it disallows the toggle for the checkbox. (When I remove the hidden input everything works fine)..

Are my css selectors accommodating for this hidden input? I may be missing something simple.

```css
.checkbox-on-off {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 35px;
  padding-right: 2px;
  overflow: hidden;
  vertical-align: middle;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

/* this positions the check box label over the text box */
.checkbox-on-off input[type=checkbox] {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}

/* makes the background blue */
.checkbox-on-off input[type=checkbox]:checked+label {
  background-color: #167ac6;
}
/* this is the grey background check mark */
.checkbox-on-off label {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  height: 15px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #b8b8b8;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

/* this adds / positions the check mark */
.checkbox-on-off input[type=checkbox]:checked+label .checked {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 3px;
  margin-left: 6px;
  background-size: auto;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}

/* if you click the checkbox, it sometimes has a grey square */
.checkbox-on-off label .checked {
  display: none;
}

.checkbox-on-off input[type=checkbox]:checked+label .unchecked {
  display: none;
}

.checkbox-on-off label .unchecked {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  padding-right: 3px;
}


#autoplay-checkbox-label
.checkbox-on-off label {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  height: 13px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #b8b8b8;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

/* this positions the white dot */
.checkbox-on-off input[type=checkbox]:checked+label .toggle {
  float: right;
}

/* this is the actual white dot */
.checkbox-on-off label .toggle {
  float: left;
  background: #fbfbfb;
  height: 15px;
  width: 13px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
<span class="checkbox-on-off ">
    <input id="autoplay-checkbox" class="" type="checkbox" checked="">
    <input name="" type="hidden" value="false">
    <label for="autoplay-checkbox" id="autoplay-checkbox-label">
        <span class="checked">&nbsp;</span>
        <span class="unchecked"></span>
        <span class="toggle">&nbsp;</span>
    </label>
</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from this selector : `input[type=checkbox]:checked+label`

It means you are targetting label which is immediately after your input (`element+element`).
Problem is your hidden `input` is between `checkbox` and `label`.

Everything works if you place your hidden `input` :

- before your `checkbox`,
- after your `label`,
- inside your `label`.

> [Live Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VYNxqg) with 3 hidden inputs

---

Update 1 :

In case you cannot modify HTML markup, you can move elements by jquery by adding `$("input[type=hidden]").prependTo("#autoplay-checkbox");`

This will move the hidden input before your checkbox

> [Updated exemple](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ogOyWK)

Comment: Awesome. Thanks! I was overlooking it. Unfortunately Razor (MVC) adds a hidden checkbox.. I'll have to find a workaround. Thanks a ton!

Comment: See update 1 in the answer for a quick workaround ;)

Comment: I thought about that method. I may end up using that. Thanks again! I wish I could upvote again!